# Which statistical test should I use for ratings?

Tags: anova, ordinal-data

I have 10 participants who were asked to rate (from 1 to 5) 30 statements. I then asked each participant to assign each statement one of three categories.

I want to establish if there is an relationship between the rating scores and the categories, i.e. do the participants rate a specific category higher than others?

Which statistical test is appropriate for this?

My initial thoughts are ANOVA but I am not sure if this violates the independence assumption. The participants often disagreed on the categorisation of some of the statements.

Comment: This will depend to some extent on how you determine the participant rating of each category from the participant rating of the statement scores.  It will also depend on how the categories were determined; did you give the participants three pre-defined categories and let them assign each statement to one, or did they get to make up their own categories?

Comment: I gave the participants pre-defined categories